# RecyclerView and ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-recyclerview

How to handle onContextItemSelected? Because I implement something like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            //menuInfo is null
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, R.string.remove);
        }
}
```

But this class hasn't onContextItemSelected method to Override, so how to handle selecting? Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a context menu, like this:

```
registerForContextMenu(yourComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, what one could do, is create a OnMenuItemClicklistener like this:-

```
final MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener groupMenuClickListener = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

    };
```

And in your context menu , once the item has been added, just set the listener on it

```
 contextMenu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, menuItems[0]);

 contextMenu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(groupMenuClickListener);
```